# Kernel compiling - cross platform

Tags: compiler-construction, cross-platform, kernel, cross-compiling

Just a small clarification about compiling kernels (not that I'm doing any :P).
What I know about compiling is that it is machine specific, although you can use a cross compiler to compile your work to run on different machine (or compile to byte-code to run under virtual machines), but cross compiling needs some basics/requirements necessary to run the program you compiled (like C++/C libs or Java VM...).

But what about kernels? they compile them once and magically run on every* machine (* didn't check that), I searched the web and I found some guide how to cross compile kernels, but didn't say why or how does it work! how does different CPUs with different instruction set run the same binary successfully?!

If you have some refs to answer my question I'll be very thankful for that, and maybe something to get me started learning more about kernels will be superb :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They don't. A kernel compiled for, say, an ARM v6 won't run on any other kind of CPU. It's the same for every binary, kernels aren't magic. And cross compiling only means that the resulting binary is specific to an architecture which is different from the architecture the compiler runs on. For example, on my x86 desktop, I can compile binaries that will run on x86, or I can cross-compile binaries that will run on, for example, PowerPC. But neither will run on the other's target platform.

Comment: So when I install linux, it detects my arch and installs the appropriate kernel for my system?

Comment: Depends on the installer/distro. The distros I use don't do anything like that, you have to choose the right installer yourself.